# How to use a galaxy's redshift to measure its distance

Tags: astrophysics, galaxies, distance

I know how we can use the spectrum emitted by a galaxy to measure whether it is redshifted/blueshifted, but out of curiosity, how can the redshift of a galaxy be used to determine its distance from us?

Comment: I recommend [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9905116) by David Hogg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the whole idea behind [Hubble's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hubble%27s_law): more distant objects recede faster (higher redshift) than closer objects. So there's a direct correlation between distance $d$ and redshift $z$

$$
d = d(z)
$$

At small distances/redshifts

$$
z = H_0d/c
$$

So, measuring $z$ gives you a direct estimation of distance